# Russian character decoding in python

Tags: python

This question only for python:

I have a city name in a string in Russian language and which is in Unicode form like,

> `\u041C\u043E\u0441\u043A\u0432\u0430`

means

> `Москва`

How to get original text instead of unicode characters?

**Note:** Do not use any import module

Comment: I am using a Interface which does not support any importing....

Comment: py3 or py2? any code snippet on how you do this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity what kind of interface doesn't allow importing?

Comment: I want just using decoding-encoding phenomenon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a=u"\u041C\u043E\u0441\u043A\u0432\u0430"
>>> print a
Москва
```

Your string is a unicode string because each character/code point with \u is only usable from a unicode string, you should prefix the string with u. Otherwise is a regular string and each \u counts as a regular ascii character:

```
>>> len(a)
6
>>> b="\u041C\u043E\u0441\u043A\u0432\u0430"
>>> len(b)
36
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to vz0 answer : Pay attention to script's encoding.

This **file** will works great :

```py
# coding: utf-8
s = u"\u041C\u043E\u0441\u043A\u0432\u0430"
print(s)
```

But this one will lead to an UnicodeEncodeError :

```py
# coding: ASCII
s = u"\u041C\u043E\u0441\u043A\u0432\u0430"
print(s)
```

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that the first declares the encoding of the source file, but `\u041C...` is perfect ASCII. If you put `coding: utf-8` the following should also work: `s = u"Москва"` because now python knows that the (source) file is encoded as utf-8 and correctly decodes the unicode.

Comment: In my environnement it doesn't work if i put `coding: ASCII` but it does with  `coding: utf-8`

Comment: Odd, for me both work (although I can't print them out because windows terminal can't properly encode it). But here I have only python 3.5.2 available, maybe how that is handled changed too.